# How do I implement acts_as_follower in comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, comments

Some assistance here gurus:

I want to implement acts_as_follower gem for my comment. The comment belongs to post and post has many comments.

I have made the comment followable by users..

And these are the Prefix verb, URI Pattern and Controller#action  from rake routes below:

post_comment_follows POST

/post/:post_id/comment/:comment_id/follows(.:format)     follows_comments#create

post_comment_follow DELETE /posts/:cjob_id/comments/:comment_id/follows/:id(.:format) follows_comments#destroy

My question is having gone through a lot of other articles on this eg:file:///C:/Users/c/Desktop/RubyOnRails/ruby%20on%20rails%20-%20acts_as_follower%20for%20multiple%20models%20-%20Stack%20Overflow.html, I have done all the necessary steps except for implementing it on the comment show page which requires post id, I tried the various method showing it, but it either says post (:id) missing or comment (:id) missing. How can I implement this on the post index please using _comment.html.erb?

Comment: Oh that was a programmer's joke lol...

Comment: Btw you must be missing some brackets.

Comment: Thank you for the observation. I have corrected it.

Comment: `arry` is still syntactically incorrect. Just open `irb` and paste the code from above...Additionally, I'm not sure how "A B" is returned from the above code. When I corrected the punctuation, `"B"` is returned (again, try in `irb` to see for yourself).

Comment: You are very observant. Thanks....corrected. Trying to reproduce things abstractly can really get confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following returns `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`:

```
#for trying out in `irb` this is fine, but I would recommend refactoring to smaller methods
[].tap do |result|
  result << arry[0].keys
  second_level_hash_names = arry.map {|hash| hash.values.map {|values_hash| values_hash["name"]}}.flatten
  third_level_hash_names = arry.map {|hash| hash.values.map {|values_hash| values_hash["sub"].map {|sub_hash| sub_hash["name"]}}}.flatten
  result << second_level_hash_names << third_level_hash_names
end.flatten
```

In your question you ask for ""A B C" OR "A B D"?" but I'm not sure which you're looking for and whether "C" or "D" is arbitrary. You can play with this code in `irb` and modify for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return "A B C" or "A B D" can do use Hash#dig something like:

```
[].tap do |result|
  result << arry[0].keys
  result << arry[0].flatten.dig(1, "name")
  result << arry[0].flatten.dig(1, "sub", 1, "name")
end.flatten
```

Output:

```
["A", "B", "D"]
```

And can change as your preference.

Comment: undefined method 'dig' for.........MethodError...That is what I am getting. I don't know why.

Comment: undefined method 'dig' for.........MethodError...That is what I am getting. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's usually better to indent the code

```
arry =[
  {"A"=>{
    "name"=>"B",
    "id"=>1,
    "sub"=>[
      {
       "name"=>"C",
       "id"=>1
      },{
        "name"=>"D",
        "id"=>2
      }
    }
   ]
```

Then you see what you need to do :

```
arry[0]['A']['sub'][0]['name'] # => 'C'
arry[0]['A']['sub'][1]['name'] # => 'D'
```

Comment: Thanks but I have tried something like this before...What I need is to have the three printed out....like "A B C".